# Wrapping the same `io.Reader` multiple times with a `bufio.Reader` and calling `ReadByte`: will this cause problems?

Tags: go, io, buffering

Suppose I have the following program
(error checking removed for simplification):

```golang
func F(r io.Reader) {
    b := make([]byte, 1)
    for ii := 0; ii < 3; ii++ {
        r.Read(b)
        if b[0] == 'f' {
            break
        }
    }
}

func G(r io.Reader) {
    b := make([]byte, 1)
    for ii := 0; ii < 3; ii++ {
        r.Read(b)
        if b[0] == 'g' {
            break
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    r, _ := os.Open("some_file.txt")
    F(r)
    G(r)
}
```

Every `r.Read`, functions `F` and `G` inspect the next byte in the `io.Reader`, and determine whether they should continue reading or not depending on the read byte.

I was thinking of rewriting the functions as follows:

```golang
func F(r io.Reader) {
    br := bufio.NewReader(r)
    for ii := 0; ii < 3; ii++ {
        if b, _ := br.ReadByte(); b == 'f' {
            break
        }
    }
}

func G(r io.Reader) {
    br := bufio.NewReader(r)
    for ii := 0; ii < 3; ii++ {
        if b, _ := br.ReadByte(); b == 'g' {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

For this case, there shouldn't be much of a reason to choose the second implementation over the first, but if we change `3` to `10000`, maybe so.

**Will wrapping `io.Reader` inside a `bufio.Reader` and calling `ReadByte` cause the original `io.Reader` to go "beyond" such that calling `G` after `F` using the same `io.Reader` may cause errors?**

Comment: The point of `bufio.Reader` is to make fewer larger Read calls to the `io.Reader` and store the data in a “buffer”. You can’t just discard that buffer without losing data.

Comment: Keep the first version & use a `bufio`, if needed, in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping buffers is redundant and will result is some extra usage of cpu/memory.

But it is not wrong.

If we are talking about small chunks of data and the cost to update the code is bigger than other tasks, perhaps you can keep this way.

My advice is to write some benchmarks. This can guide you to find where you should focus.

But you can:

1. Force the parameter to be an `*bufio.Reader` in G, F
2. Keep io.Reader as parameter. Check if it is a bufio.Reader and if not, wrap it.
3. Consider chain the functions

```golang
type Consumer func(io.Reader)

type ChainConsumer func(Consumer) Consumer

func G(r io.Reader) {
   // same code
}

func ChainedF(next Consumer) Consumer {
    return func(r io.Reader){
        // F here, then
    
        next(r)
    }
}

func ChainedBuffered(next Consumer) Consumer {
    return func(r io.Reader){
        br := bufio.NewReader(r)

        next(br)
    }
}
…
r, _ := os.Open(…)

chain :=
ChainedBuffered(ChainedF(G))

chain(r) // voila
```